# Running Django command /generating index with manage.py

Tags: python, django, postgresql, elasticsearch

I need to run to Heroku a web job that every night needs to generate the index for Elasticsearch, I wanted to know if is possible. The command that I need to run on the python shell automatically are:

```py
heroku run python3 manage.py shell --app My_app
    
from myapp.search_tasks import delete_index, create_index, index_all;
    
delete_index(); create_index(); index_all();
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: You normally do this with a *management command*: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/#management-commands-and-locales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a [management command [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/#management-commands-and-locales) to do this. In your app you create the `management/` and `commands/` directories:

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    management/
        commands/
            make_es_index.py
    models.py
    views.py
    urls.py
```

Then in the `make_es_index.py`, you can define that command:

```
# my_app/management/commanheroku addons:open schedulerds/make_es_index.py

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, no_translations

from myapp.search_tasks import delete_index, create_index, index_all

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        delete_index()
        create_index()
        index_all()
```

Next we can schedule the task in Heroku, for example with the [*Heroku Scheduler*](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler). We install the add-on with:

```
heroku addons:create scheduler:standard
```

next we create a task in `bin/refresh-es-index`:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd 'root/of/django-project'
python3 manage.py make_es_index
```

Next we can schedule the `refresh-es-index` task with:

```
heroku addons:open scheduler
```

and set the time interval when we need to run the job.

Comment: Thank you Willem, exactly what I need!!